# Dynamic Saving and refreshing

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a form that is generated by dynamic drop downs(Country/State/City). As of right now when a user clicks to update the information they have entered, it brings them back to the beginning screen where they have to go through the process of selecting the specific destination affiliated to the change.

Is there a way I can get the submit button to display everything the just saved including the options in the drop down box? Or possibly is there a way to just get the submit button to not refresh the entire page?

Here is the code for my submit-

```
<input type="hidden" name="addedit" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Update City" name="Update_City"align="center"style="background:#e5f9bb; cursor:pointer; cursor:hand;" />
```

And for the php update-

```
 if (isset($_POST['Update_City'])){
 //stuff
 $SQL = "UPDATE city SET.....etc 
 }
```

Comment: Can you provide js code please?

Comment: I have nothing in my JavaScript that relates to my submit button.

Comment: Ok, and where you call the php-script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

- Not to refresh the page make AJAX call.

In this case whatever communication you do with the backend would be async and you needn't refresh the page thereby preserving the form values.

- Pre-fill the form values on refresh.

When you submit your form, you know the values submitted by the user. You may use them prefill the the options.

eg. in PHP for select elements you can set the attribute selected if $_POST["variable"] is that specific value.

Comment: I will probably use the option not to refresh the page.